# Undefined is not an object (evaluating auth.confirmResult)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Getting Error in LoginScreen.js component when trying to access state property "confirmResult" through props in Render Function after doing MapsStatetoProps and connect().

**Screens\LoginScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PhoneInput from "react-native-phone-input";
import { View, StatusBar, Text } from "react-native";
import { Container, Item, Input, Button } from "native-base";
import { firebaseAuth } from "../Config/firebase";
import { phoneChanged } from "../Actions/AuthActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export class LoginScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      valid: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.unsubscribe) this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#4F6D7A" }}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#062b40" />
        <Text>This is LoginScreen</Text>
        <Container
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            backgroundColor: "#4F6D7A"
          }}
        >
          {auth.confirmResult}
        </Container>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(state) + "*************");
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { phoneChanged }
)(LoginScreen);
```

**AuthReducer.js**

```
import {
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_USER,
  PHONE_CHANGED,
  CODE_SENT_ERROR,
  CODE_CHANGED,
  CODE_DISPATCHED,
  LOGIN_USER_PHONE,
  CODE_SENT,
  CODE_NOT_CONFIRMED,
  LOGOUT,
  SET_USER_OBJECT,
  CLEAR_AUTH
} from "../Actions/ActionTypes";

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  phone: "+91",
  user: null,
  message: "",
  loading: false,
  codeInput: "",
  confirmResult: null
};

const AuthReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case PHONE_CHANGED:
      return {
        ...state,
        phone: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default AuthReducer;
```

**Reducers\index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer
});
```

**Root.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Navigator } from "./Navigation/index";
import { store } from "./Store/index";
import LoginContainer from "./Screens/LoginScreen";

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Store\index.js**

```
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import reducer from "../Reducers/index";

let composeEnhancers = compose;
/*  eslint no-undef: 0    */
if (__DEV__) {
  /*  eslint no-underscore-dangle: 0    */
  composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  {},
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
);

export { store };
```

**Actions\AuthActions.js**

```
//import { firebase } from "react-native-firebase";
import * as actionTypes from "./ActionTypes";
import { auth } from "../Config/firebase";

const phoneChanged = text => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.PHONE_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};

export { phoneChanged };
```

**Navigation\index.js**

```
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from "react-navigation";
import AuthLoading from "../Screens/AuthLoading";
import HomeScreen from "../Screens/HomeScreen";
import { LoginScreen } from "../Screens/LoginScreen";

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen
});

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "AuthLoading"
  }
);

export const Navigator = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-otp-inputs": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Should not throw error and props should be able to access state property.

Comment: your code seems to be ok, maybe the problem comes from the constructor, you should call super with the props `constructor(props) {
    super(props);...`

Comment: This did not work. Getting same error.

Comment: Do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(state))` in your `mapStateToProps` and see if there's a `confirmResult` property on the `auth` property. You should also consider using a name other than `auth` in your `render` function, since you've defined `auth` as an import.

Comment: Hi Hectic Monkey, i changed auth in import to firebaseAuth but it did not work. I tried doing console.log(JSON.stringify(state)) in your mapStateToProps but is not coming in logs. May be not able to reach that part of code. I have updated the code with these changes.

Comment: The issues is version issue problem explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065198/invariant-violation-invalid-hooks-call-hooks-call-can-only-be-made-inside-bod

Answer (score 0):

Modify your constructor as follow:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    ........
}
```

Store index file as follow:

```
import reducer from "../Reducer/index"
```

Root File as follow:

```
import { Navigator } from "./Navigation/index"

import { store } from "./Store/index"
```

Navigation/index as follow:

```
import LoginScreen from "../Screens/LoginScreen"
```

React-redux (> 7.0.1) uses hook &
React-native (< 0.59) doesn’t support Hooks yet.

You can run `npm ls react-native` in your application folder to check which version you’re using.

If you find more than one of them, this might also create problems. [more on it](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

**There are two solution**

Upgrade the react native version to 0.59.0

OR

Downgrade the react redux version to 6.0.1

I hope it help you.

Comment: This did not work. Getting same error.

Comment: check store index file you've import reducer from "../Reducers/index" But it's actual path is "../Reducer/index".

Comment: Sorry That was typo error i my are in Reducers\index.js , otherwise that would have thrown error of "component not found". I tried you approach of changes Index.js to index.js but it does not work.

Comment: check this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@muhammadmehar/redux-navigation-and-simple-example).

Comment: Also edit firebase config file before preview on snack.

Comment: I made changes according to your Snack - 1. Removed export from "export class LoginScreen" in LoginScreen.js but i am getting error of "Invalid hooks call". I was earlier facing this issues so i added export statement to it and was using named import like " import { LoginScreen }" in Navigation/index.js. In the snack you did not export LoginScreen how are you able to import that in Navigation\index.js??

Comment: check the import statement of "Navigation/index" in snack it is as follow: " import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen' ".

Comment: If you export a module with default keyword like `export default moduleName`, then you need to import it like this way `import moduleName from "modulePath"`. Similarly, if exported without default keyword like `export class moduleName`, then you need to import it like this way `import { moduleName } from "modulePath"`.

Comment: I am getting error of "Invariant violation: invalid hooks call" on using your code. One Question the import LoginScreen is a container component so how its used as Presentational component in Navigator in line of screen : LoginScreen?  I don't have enough reputation to chat , can you share you gmail account so that we can sync over google hangout.

Comment: can you share your package.json dependencies & devDependencies with versions number?

Comment: Added Package.json

Answer (score 0):

About the 2nd argument of [createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore):

> [`preloadedState`] (*any*): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it.

So the `{}` overwrites the initial state and it won't be `{auth: ...}` as expected... It should be possible to just skip the argument as in the [compose](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) example, e.g.:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
);
```

Comment: I tried the above approach but it is not working.