# Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call with React-Redux Connect #15822

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to react native and I am trying to implement Redux in my application. React native throwing error while using connect function from react-redux as follows.

```
export default connect()(MyComponent);
```

I checked all 3 options and I am not breaking any:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks(Not sure)
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

**Version of dependancies listed below:**

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.57.7",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
"react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
"react-native-maps": "https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps.git",
"react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
"react-native-size-matters": "^0.1.4",
"react-native-super-grid": "^3.0.4",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
"react-redux": "^7.0.3",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
```

Error disappear when I remove connect(). But it prevents from implanting Redux

Is this a bug in React Native or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you using react hooks? That is the proper way to use the connect method, so something else must be going on

Comment: I am on react-native 0.57. So I think its not available to me. Am I correct? What else you think can be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invariant Violation : Invalid Hooks Call. Hooks Call can only be made inside body of function components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065198/invariant-violation-invalid-hooks-call-hooks-call-can-only-be-made-inside-bod)

Comment: Sergey Shvager is right. Also, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56210647/5563191

Answer (score 1):

Try to update react-native to 0.59.x.

Looks like react-redux switched to use React hooks internally. But react-native added React hooks support starting from version 0.59 (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059).